# Adding breakpoints to FlexSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, flexslider

I am using FlexSlider to create a responsive gallery using some instruction from [this site](http://2002-2012.mattwilcox.net/archive/entry/id/1088/). I really was just wondering if there is a way to use the breakpoints to set a variable (1,2,3 etc) rather than duplicating a bunch of code. The only settings that change with the breakpoints are 'minItems' and 'maxItems' and it seems silly to set everything again. So, basically just trying to clean up the JavaScript and make it more concise.

FlexSlider: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

**HTML**

```
<div class="flexslider-container">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="image1.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="image2.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="image3.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="image4.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* breakpoint_1 */
body:after { display: none; content: 'breakpoint_1'; }
.flexslider { max-width: 1080px; margin : 0 auto; }

/* breakpoint_2 */
@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
body:after { display: none; content: 'breakpoint_2'; }
}
/* breakpoint_3 */
@media all and (min-width: 720px) {
body:after { display: none; content: 'breakpoint_3'; }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentBreakpoint;
  var didResize  = true;
  var raw_slider = $(".flexslider").html();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    didResize = true;
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    if(didResize) {
      didResize = false;

      var newBreakpoint = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':after').getPropertyValue('content');

      newBreakpoint = newBreakpoint.replace(/"/g, "");
      newBreakpoint = newBreakpoint.replace(/'/g, "");

      if (currentBreakpoint != newBreakpoint) {

        $(".flexslider").remove();

        $(".flexslider-container").append("<div class='flexslider'></div>");
        $(".flexslider").html(raw_slider);

        if (newBreakpoint === 'breakpoint_1') {
          currentBreakpoint = 'breakpoint_1';

          $(".flexslider").flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            animationLoop: false,
            itemWidth: 360,
            itemMargin: 0,
            minItems: 1,
            maxItems: 1,
            controlNav: false
          });
        }
        if (newBreakpoint === 'breakpoint_2') {
          currentBreakpoint = 'breakpoint_2';

          $(".flexslider").flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            animationLoop: false,
            itemWidth: 360,
            itemMargin: 0,
            minItems: 2,
            maxItems: 2,
            controlNav: false
          });
        }
        if (newBreakpoint === 'breakpoint_3') {
          currentBreakpoint = 'breakpoint_3';

          $(".flexslider").flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            animationLoop: false,
            itemWidth: 360,
            itemMargin: 0,
            minItems: 3,
            maxItems: 3,
            controlNav: false
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }, 250);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function as the value of minItems and maxItems, as per [this example](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/dynamic-carousel-min-max.html). Code:

```
(function() {
 
  // store the slider in a local variable
  var $window = $(window),
      flexslider = { vars:{} };
 
  // tiny helper function to add breakpoints
  function getGridSize() {
    return (window.innerWidth < 600) ? 2 :
           (window.innerWidth < 900) ? 3 : 4;
  }
 
  $(function() {
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
  });
 
  $window.load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      animationLoop: false,
      itemWidth: 210,
      itemMargin: 5,
      minItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
      maxItems: getGridSize() // use function to pull in initial value
    });
  });
 
  // check grid size on resize event
  $window.resize(function() {
    var gridSize = getGridSize();
 
    flexslider.vars.minItems = gridSize;
    flexslider.vars.maxItems = gridSize;
  });
}());
```